# Can We delete many columns as UltraEdit in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, text, ultraedit

in order to  delete the follow "    NSString *"

```
NSString * todayDate;
NSString * conditionStatus;
NSString * ftemp;
NSString * ctemp;
NSString * imageUrl;
```

make it like below once

```
 todayDate;
 conditionStatus;
 ftemp;
 ctemp;
 imageUrl;
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can do a simple *Find & Replace* with find string as `NSString *` and leaving the replace string as `empty`.

2) You can simply press `option/alt` key while you select the *columns* in *Xcode* and press the `delete` button. Pressing the *option/alt* key while selecting text lets you select the texts as columns.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, just do a *find and replace* (command + f) with the string `NSString *`, and a blank space, and that will get the job done. Hope that Helps!